# function for TextView in viewDidLoad (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have code to display the number of input characters in TextView.

Whether it is possible to make so that at start of the controller the server showed quantity of characters and not only print.

How can I put it in viewDidLoad?

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        let newText = (viewText.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
        let numberOfChars = newText.characters.count
        Characters.text = ("\(numberOfChars) characters")
        return numberOfChars < 10000
}
```

Comment: `shouldChangeTextIn` is the wrong place since that shows how many characters are in place just before the text view is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use to count character textViewDidChange in place of shouldChangeTextIn.Inside textViewDidChange write this code.

```
//**Swift 4.0**
public func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView){
    print("textViewDidChange")
    let counter = textView.text.count
    print(counter)

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Define it elsewhere and call it in your `viewDidLoad()`

```
@override func viewDidLoad() {
 textView(myTextView, myRange, myReplacement)
}
```

You can define it in the class or as a module

You could also paste the code in your `viewDidLoad()` and replace the variables with the values you would otuerwise call the function with